# viewDidLoad method is calling again after setting nil to tableView in UITableViewController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am using UITableViewController in my applicaton. While pop from tableview controller   to back, i was setting nil to table view to deallocate the view controller from memory. its again calling viewDidLoad, please explain me why it is happening.

```
-(void)handleBackButton{
        self.tableView=nil;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what? show us some code of all

Comment: I am overriding the back button event of UINavigationController and also setting self.tableView=nil, in that method. at that time it's happening.

Comment: Without code it is hard to help you. One thing: When you set self.tableView=nil, you are deallocation the table view, not the table view controller.

Comment: There's no need to set the table view to nil. When you pop the table view controller off the stack, it and its views will be deallocated.

Comment: Please find my updated edit. Sorry for my typing mistake.

Comment: its not calling automatically, because its having too many chaildviews . So that i am manually setting nil to that object then it's calling viewDidLoad and after that its calling dealloc.

Comment: Do you have a strong reference to this view being popped off of the stack?

Comment: if i remove that dealloc method is not calling.

Comment: @Dear Helium can you please explain me in which conditions viewDidLoad method will be called?

Comment: @Kondamoori: viewDidLoad: of which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and look at the stack trace to see why it's reloading its view.

But I can make an educated guess.  When you tell the navigation controller to pop a view controller, it needs to animate that view controller's `view` off the screen.  To do so, it probably asks the disappearing view controller for its `view`.

A `UITableViewController`'s `view` is the same as its `tableView`.  When you set `tableView` to `nil`, you also set `view` to `nil`.  So when the navigation controller asks the table view controller for its `view` (so it can animate the view off the screen), the table view controller notices that its `view` is nil, so it loads its view.  And to load its view, it sends itself `loadView` and then it sends itself `viewDidLoad`.

I don't know why you would really bother trying to unload the view.  If the view controller itself gets deallocated, it will release its view (which will deallocate the view unless you've retained it somewhere else).  And if the view controller doesn't get deallocated, isn't that usually because you might want to put its view back on the screen soon?

Anyway, if you really want to get rid of a view controller's view, don't set its `view` to `nil` while the view might still be in the on-screen view hierarchy.  Wait until the view is definitely out of the hierarchy.  For example, subclass `UITableViewController`, and override `didMoveToParentViewController:` like this:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parentViewController {
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];
    if (parentViewController == nil) {
        self.tableView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Your guess is correct, exactly  same thing happening here.